# MSTest Reused codedUI

Tags: c#, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a series of MS Unit tests in a class that I have created called Forename. The all run and pass sucessfully to test a variety of inputs e.g 100 chars max etc

I am now looking at getting CodedUI to find the forename and execute these test. I have managed to do this for one specific web page that has the forename control. I have managed to get this all working and pass.

I have now introduced a second page and I want to re-use the same set of test methods, and not have to repeat the code. I can defind and interface and implement and extract some methods to allow some re-use. I have tried to use inheritace, but am struggling and need some guidance if this is possible with MS Test.

Ideally I want to navigate to the page and run the forename tests. I then want to go to the second page and execute the extact same test.

All help appreciated.

Comment: So really you are looking for a way to reuse your MSTest classes with different instances of a UIMap from CodedUI?

Comment: Possibly, but in my coded UI at present I am not using UIMaps.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a data driven test: [How To: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx)

Comment: not really as I am attempting to reused test methods in multiple test classes

Comment: Which is the use case for a data driven test. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want some guidance on how to set up CodedUI tests in such a way that they become maintainable. I can recommend you look at a concept called the PageObject pattern. 
[Page Object pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

You can do this with either the UIMap files you record, but personaly I like a code First approach better. You can find more details on writing codedUI without UI Map files [here](http://fluentbytes.com/using-codedui-testautomation-without-uimap-files/)

It not only describes how you can map your web application to page objects, it also describes a way to build build out a Fluent API that makes your tests very easy to read and better maintainable.

Hope that helps.